# Data transfer rate and volume from web server to client

Tags: java, javascript, http, webserver, client

I am writing a web app that runs on tomcat. I need to transfer around 25 kb of data (all double/long values every 20 ms from server to client.) Trying to use server-sent events for this, as I just need one one way communication channel from server to client.

Using java at server side and java script at client side.

Please suggest if what I am talking here makes sense at all and if it is achievable.

I am new to web development.

Comment: I'd think about using WebSockets. Server-send events are that widely supported in frameworks and browsers (e.g. IE10).

Comment: I think you meant server sent events are NOT widely supported. Thats ok, my concern is such data volume and such rate of transfer is achievable over http ? I understand that this can be a very trivial question, but I am struggling to answer this.  :( Please help.

Comment: It's not so trivial. There are a lot of things to consider: network bandwith and latency, what are you going to do with the data on the client side? One thing i would definitely not do, is using such an application over a common internet connection.

Comment: ok .. but I am trying to know whats the bottle neck at technology end .. if any .. lets say we have infinite bandwidth or everything is on local (same machine) for that matter.  What bottlenecks HTTP or server sent events brings into the picture .. if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try it yourself - you will notice a big difference between localhost and an actual network:

Servlet (Generates 25kb big messages):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "EventServlet", urlPatterns = {"/EventServlet"}, asyncSupported = true)
public class EventServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/event-stream; charset=utf-8");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "Chunked");
        response.flushBuffer();
        final AsyncContext ctx = request.startAsync();
        ctx.setTimeout(0);

        ctx.start(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    Writer out = ctx.getResponse().getWriter();
                    for (;;) {
                        out.write("event: simpleEvent\n");
                        out.write("data:" + randomString(25000) + "\n\n");
                        ctx.getResponse().flushBuffer();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    ctx.complete();
                }

            }
        });

    }
    private static final String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private static Random rnd = new Random();

    public static String randomString(int len) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>Number of Messages</div>
        <div id="out">

        </div>
        <div>Messages per Second:</div>

        <div id="mean">

        </div>

    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        var counter = 0;

        var eventSource = new EventSource("EventServlet");

        eventSource.addEventListener('simpleEvent', function(event){
            counter++;
            document.getElementById("out").innerHTML=counter;

            var seconds = (new Date().getTime()-startTime)/1000;
            document.getElementById("mean").innerHTML=counter/seconds;
        },false);

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot alex. I will try that. Currently I am outside, so out of curiosity, if you have tried as it (As it seems) , what is the result ? How long it took ...

Comment: 2000 messages per second on localhost. Around 60 messages per seconds with two machines in a (wireless) local network. Your break even is at 50. So it's very close and you have to count in, what you are doing with the data on the client. But again, if you habe a 10G Network with latency <1ms this might look completely different.

Comment: Alex, thanks a ton for such gr8 response & taking out time for this. You taught me the lesson, so start trying things myself even if I am new to all this. I would like to have your opinion on the bigger picture. 25kb is meter reading data for few thousand meters (2 double values for each meter). I want to plot the real time data in graph. Not of all them together, but whatever user request. But I do want to cache all data on client side for some time window (10 sec.).Please suggest what will be right way to do this. (redndering 10 points very 200ms or something instead of 1 point every 20ms)

Comment: Please let me know if I didn't put it in right words .. I would elaborate more.. but I seriously need your view on this

Comment: Im not sure, if this is the right way to do this. Transfering 25K every 20 ms is a lot of data. Have you thought about just sending the currently needed data. If the user changes his selection, close the currently running EventSource and open up a new one. You can open the EventSource with url parameters (e.g. var eventSource = new EventSource("EventServlet?selection="+selection);). The servlet can read that parameter and send you just the neeeded data.

Comment: Regarding your caching question. There are two apis to save data on the client: LocalStorage and IndexDB (of course there are cookies - but they are not applicable in this case). IndexDB being the newer one and is not supported by all browsers. LocalStorage is a classic key/value store. Querying a LocalStorage by key is really fast. So it is very importend that you have a good key / hashing strategy for your data. For LocalStorage there is still a maximum size which is different in modern browsers.

Comment: Both of replies are amazing & of tremendous use.Just 1 quick last thing. Writing a java swing desktop app ,where all the data transfer takes place on sockets (hope I am not wrong), by any chance is a better option & has it any pro and cons over web app idea (apart from accessibility etc.)if we just focus on massive data volume that needs to be sent to client.Yes I can just sent what user asks for, but I have to change color of nodes in a node graph based on these,so all data is needed.May be server can be programmed to send value of a reading (attribute) only if it is different from previous.

Comment: I don't know anything about your working parameters or client needs. And I'm definitely biased. If a customer askes me about client strategy, i will most likely always opt for web-browsers. But you have to try to put most of the computation and the data-storage on the server. Try to keep the app servers stateless so you can scale the application by adding more servers.

Comment: That is a very wise advice.  Any thoughts on swing apps / desktop apps ? Is there anything inherent to them, which gives them an edge over web apps when it comes to such huge volume of data coming at such a pace (20 ms).